# MATLAB text output justification?

Tags: matlab, text, command-prompt, justify

I am outputting the following in MATLAB:

```
fprintf(['######### Identification FINISHED #########\n\n'...
         'Results:\n\n'...
         'lambda_T = %.4f%15.3s *Static*\n'...
         'lambda_F = %.4f%15.3s *Static*\n'...
         'c_d      = %.4f%15.3s *Static*\n'...
         'kappa    = %.4f%15.8s *Static*\n'...
         'lambda_W = %.4f%15s *Dynamic*\n'...
         'sigma_0  = %.4E%15s *Dynamic*\n'...
         'Theta    = %.4f%15s *Dynamic*\n\n'],...
         lambda_T,'[-]',lambda_F,'[-]',c_d,'[-]',kappa,'[V*s]',...
         lambda_W,'[-]',sigma_0,'[1/Pa]',Theta,'[kg*m^2]');
```

[image]

I would like to have the text circled in blue above to be right-justified along the red line, while the text circled in green remains as it is. How can I do this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Find out the maximum length of a line, thus start until red line, then white-space pad either the green or the blue column of each line on basis of that length.

Comment: Sure, but I'm looking for an automated way that MATLAB maybe has to do this? I recall something like this being available in the Linux terminal when outputting strings in C++.

Comment: Yea, this can be automated. I don't have MATLAB with me atm, so I can't check it now, but it should look something like: save all your strings, find max length, then recreate everything with `max(allstr)-length(tmpstr)` and pad according to that.